# How to constrain search to latest entry in Laravel query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I use `->latest()` in my query builder in Laravel it returns the latest query that matches other conditions but I want to constrain my query to only the latest object + my conditions, rather than select the entry that conforms to my conditions and is the latest.

So for example if there is this table:

| id | name | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | 2020-10-01 |
| 2 | Jack | 2020-10-02 |
| 3 | Jeff | 2020-10-03 |

`Student::where('id', 2)->latest()->first();` returns an instance of student 'Jack'.

But I want it to return `null`, as there is no student with `id` of 2, which is the also latest.

Put another way: It should only ever return 'Jeff' or `null` as that is the latest entry.

How would I perform this query?

EDIT: I'm putting in the `created_at` column to make it clear that I want the query to be limited by the `latest()` condition + some other condition (in this case `id`).

Comment: You are using where so it will get student with id 2 , the latest function will just add order by desc; like so : `select 'students'.* from 'students' where 'id' = ? order by 'created_at' desc`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply return the `latest()` record from database and check if its have the desired id in a `if condition`

```
$student=Student::latest()   
        ->first('id');
        if($student->id==2){
            return null;
        }
        return $student;
```

Comment: can I do that within the query though? With many records this makes for an expensive query

Comment: It's one query either way. You can reduce the data that's retrieved by only selecting the id column

Comment: in my situation though I am perhaps retrieving many entries as this `latest()` is applied in a `whereHas()` query for a related model. So I dont want to retrieve many entries with a relation that is the latest and then loop through and apply an `if` statement to each entry.

Comment: You can check the student id another callback function in `whereHas()`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. If I do:
`Model::whereHas('subModel', function ($query) {
$query->latest();
})->whereHas('subModel', function ($query) {$query->where('someField', 1);
});`
Then it does not return the true latest entry for `subModel` but rather the latest entry where the second condition in the second `whereHas` is true.
`

Answer (score 0):

Both work for your Question (I prefer 2nd Query):

```
App\Student::where('id', function($query){ $query->select('id')->from('students')->latest()->limit(1);})->first()

App\Student::where('id', function($query){ $query->selectRaw("max(id)")->from('students');})->first()
```